# Clicking popup button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do a function that 
if `class="btn btn-default"` exists 
click them 
this would be problematic bcz there are more btn defaults besides this ones :D

**so how do i work with the "Chest unlocked"**

```
<div class="chest_container">
                      <div class="chest unlocked"></div>
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="daily_bonus_content">
    <div class="rewards_grid">
                    <div class="reward day_1">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="chest_container">
                        <div class="chest unlocked"></div>
                        <div class="day">1</div>
                        <div class="actions"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Abrir</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="reward day_2">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="chest_container">
                        <div class="chest"></div>
                        <div class="day">2</div>
                        <div class="actions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="reward day_3">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="chest_container">
                        <div class="chest"></div>
                        <div class="day">3</div>
                        <div class="actions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="reward day_4">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="chest_container">
                        <div class="chest"></div>
                        <div class="day">4</div>
                        <div class="actions"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question and break the code down to a minimal example?

Comment: yeah i did edit please

Answer (score 0):

In vanillaJS, clicking every btn-default in a chest_container

```
var buttons = document.querySelector(".chest_container .btn-default");
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.click();
});
```

If you catch the click in an event, you can reach the chest_unlocked by doing the following, where e is the event:

```
var chestUnlockedDiv = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".chest.unlocked");
```